# Basic clickable item in android

Tags: java, android, user-interface, button

I've been searching for this for quite a while but can't seem to find it.

Is there any predefined widget in Android to implement a basic clickable item (with one of two lines of text) whose background turns to the theme's color when clicked, like the ones seen here, for example:

[image]

And I mean, without using the PreferenceActivity class, which implements this automatically. Does this exist or do I have to implement my own customized view?

Thanks!

Edit:

I've added a TwoLineListItem like this and it doesn't react to clicks (background doesn't change)

```
    <TwoLineListItem
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    >

    <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Meh" />

    <TextView android:id="@android:id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/text1"
        android:paddingBottom="4dip"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:text="Moo" />

</TwoLineListItem>
```

Does it only work inside ListViews? Because that way I'll have to define my buttons in code and not in the XML, right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default layout for that is called [android.R.two_line_list_item](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.layout.html#two_line_list_item) given by android.

Answer (score 0):

All the items in a ListView support this transition.

Best wishes,
Tim

Comment: Ah, so you mean using ListItems as buttons. Thanks!